# How I can change auth level of azure functions and secure it?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am having an azure function and i want to change authlevel of my azure function from `authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS` to `FUNCTION` or `ADMIN`. How I can implement and I am using java spring boot function app?

Code:

```
@FunctionName("funcName")
public HttpResponseMessage execute(@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = { HttpMethod.GET,HttpMethod.POST }, 
authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) 
HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
ExecutionContext context){
<------body ------>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change

```
authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS
```

To

```
authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION

Or

authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ADMIN
```

=========================update====================

Your URL endpoint might look like this format:

```
https://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>?code=<API_KEY>
```

And you can find API_KEY here:

[image]

For more details, you can refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#obtaining-keys).

Comment: Do I need to add any security token or any key ? And what will be the URL endpoint!

Comment: Based on the "Auth level" you choose, you will have to provide the key. You can get the URL from the "Get Function Url" option at your Function page an example of which Frank has provided above.
Check this documentation for more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp&source=docs#http-auth

Comment: This might be helpful to understand the available Auth level parameters for the JavaScript client: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-javascript#http-auth

`"authLevel": "function"` (small caps)